# As overload the method compare the Comparator interface?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I am developing a small application , I have an "Employee" class with methods and corresponding attributes (name , salary , date .. ) and another class that is a list of employees , which I use an arraylist to store employees and different methods , such as adding employee , delete employee .

Now I 'm trying to sort employees by alphabetical order and date of hire (lowest to highest).

But I have a little problem, I can not use the method compare more than 2 times, I have been researching and not whether it could overload the method compare to sort employees by name and date .
thanks.

```
    public class Employee
      {

        private String name;
        private GregorianCalendar dateHire;

     public GregorianCalendar getDateHire() {  return  dateHire;  }

  public void setDateHire(GregorianCalendar  dateHire) { this.dateHire =  dateHire; }


public getName() { return name;}

public setName (String name) { this.name = name;}



     }
```

//------------------------------------------------------

```
  public class listEmployee implements Comparator <Employee>
   {

           ArrayList<Employee> Employees = new ArrayList<>();

              @Override
            public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
                if (e1.getName() != e2.getName()) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }  


// now , when I call this function in the parent class , if you sort the names , now when I try 
//to sort dates , not let me use the method compare more than twice

     public void sortAlphabetical() {

            Collections.sort(trabajadores,Employee.StuNameComparator);
        }

        //I was looking online and found these options, but not as a call in the main class

              public static Comparator <Employee > sortDate = new Comparator<Employee >()
            {

                @Override
                public int compare (Employee s1, Employee s2)
                {
                   GregorianCalendar empTemporal = s1.getDateHire();
                     GregorianCalendar emTemporal2 = s2.getDateHire();

                     return  empTemporal.compareTo(emTemporal2);

                }


            };





          public static Comparator <Employee> StuNameComparator = new Comparator<Employee >() {

                @Override
            public int compare(Employee  s1, Employee  s2) {
               String EmployeName1 = s1.getName().toUpperCase();
               String EmployeName2 = s2.getName().toUpperCase();

               //ascending order
               return EmployeName1.compareTo( EmployeName2);

               //descending order
               //return StudentName2.compareTo(StudentName1);
            }};
            }
```

Comment: Your confusing me with your use of both Spanish and English. What is the name of your class, Employee? Empleado?? Please stick to one or the other. Please proof-read your questions **before** posting them.

Comment: And yes, the solution is to use Comparable for implementing the "natural ordering" of the class, and to use a Comparator (or Comparators if you need more than one) when you need to sort in a way that is not the "natural ordering" of the class. So how does your current code not work?

Comment: Maybe it is not working, because you compare objects `!=` not Strings `.equals()`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've already corrected

Answer (score 1):

You can't overload the `compare` method of the `Comparator<Employee>` interface, since there is just one signature to that method - `int compare(Employee  s1, Employee  s2)`.

However, you can have multiple classes that implement that interface, and you can choose the relevant `Comparator<Employee>` implementation whenever you wish to sort your `Employee` list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two methods, you just need that single method with logic to take the name into consideration first and then the hire date:

```
@Override
public int compare(Empleado e1, Empleado e2) {
    int nameCompare = e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName());
    if (nameCompare != 0) {
        return nameCompare;
    }
    return e1.getDateHire().compareTo(e2.getDateHire());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding. Well I think I have solved, that is, using this code in class employee and then implementing the function in list of employees , it has worked.

```
 public class Employee
      {

        private String name;
        private GregorianCalendar dateHire;

     public GregorianCalendar getDateHire() {  return  dateHire;  }

  public void setDateHire(GregorianCalendar  dateHire) { this.dateHire =  dateHire; }


public getName() { return name;}

public setName (String name) { this.name = name;}


 public static Comparator <Employee > HireDateComparator = new Comparator<Employee >()
{

    @Override
    public int compare (Employees1, Employee s2)
    {
       GregorianCalendar empTemporal = s1.getfechaContratacion();
         GregorianCalendar emTemporal2 = s2.getfechaContratacion();


       empTemporal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     emTemporal2.get(Calendar.YEAR);



         return  empTemporal.compareTo(emTemporal2);

    }


};

     public static Comparator <Employee > StuNameComparator = new Comparator<Employee >() {

        @Override
    public int compare(Employee  s1, Employee  s2) {
       String StudentName1 = s1.getName().toUpperCase();
       String StudentName2 = s2.getName().toUpperCase();

       //ascending order
       return StudentName1.compareTo(StudentName2);

       //descending order
       //return StudentName2.compareTo(StudentName1);
    }};




     }
```

---

```
 public class listEmployee 
{
        ArrayList<Employee> Employees = new ArrayList<>();


      public void sortAlphabetical() {

        Collections.sort( Employees, Employee.StuNameComparator);
    }

    public void sortByDate() {

        Collections.sort(Employees, Employee.HireDateComparator);

    }




}
```

---

and if someone wants to try in the main class ....

```
public class ArrayList {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

   listEmployee createEmployes = new listEmployee ();

   createEmployes.sortAlphabetical();

  createEmployes.sortByDate();


}




}
```